# Homogeneous Poisson Processes with rate λ

Tags: descriptive-statistics

[image]

I don‘t understand the last line, why Ui is uniform distribution in (0,1) rather than in (0,f(x)/λ)

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps add a Poisson tag?

Answer (score 1):

If $U \sim$ uniform$(0, 1)$ then it is true that $- \log(U) / \lambda$ is distributed exponential$(\lambda)$.  To see this we can compute the distribution function (note the inequality flips when we multiply by $- \lambda$):

\begin{align}
P(- \log(U) / \lambda \leq x) &= P(U \geq e^{- \lambda x}) \\
&= 1 - P(U \leq e^{- \lambda x}) \\
&= 1 - e^{- \lambda x} .
\end{align}